# Is there a way to search filtered media of both posts and retweets by people I follow?

Tags: twitter

In Twitter, you can search both `filter:media` and `filter:media filter:nativeretweets` separately with people you follow (`pf=on`) on. It will either give you media posted by people you follow, or it will give you media reposted by people you follow, but it won't show you both? I tried different approaches like `filter:media OR filter:nativeretweets` but nothing seem to work. Any workaround for this problem?